# How can I calculate Posterior Distribution, analytically with given information?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, inference

My apology for stating my question with an image. The following image shows that the posterior distribution is as follows with the given information:

[image]

I wonder how the posterior has been calculated, analytically.

Comment: You should explain why you cannot compute $p(\theta|x)$ from $p(\theta)$ and $p(x|\theta)$.

Comment: I am new to Bayesain Statistics and trying to understand how the above question is derived from the given information.

Comment: You should at least know how to move from the pair prior x likelihood to the posterior

Comment: I gave it a go and solved the question. When I uploaded the question, I didn't have a clue how to calculate it but now I can. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $ x=1 $

$ \dfrac{p(\theta)p(x=1 | \theta)}{p(\theta_1)p(x=1 | \theta) + p(\theta_2)p(x=1 | \theta_2)} = \dfrac{p(0)p(x=1 | 0)}{p(0)p(x=1|0)+p(1)p(x=1|1)} = \dfrac{0.1665}{0.417} = 0.399280576 \approx 0.4$

So, when $ x=0 $, the probability of $ x=0 $ is $ 0.6 $

Comment: The use of slightly incorrect decimal approximations, written out in excessive precision, makes this calculation somewhat confusing: the answer $3/5$ is *exact,* not approximate.